# Gridview with textfields

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2010, gridview

[image: hello how to do a gridview lik this]

hello,
    i want to create a grid view from two tables in database. and bind it together and update it another table in the database. Customer_Name is one column from BillingData table and Group_Name is another column from GroupMapping. and the remaining fields should be text fields where use can enter the values.

Comment: Please show what have you done on it so far.

Comment: @Yogendra well i'm a fresher and i donot know how to combine two tables and get a view like that

Comment: It's hard to read the photo when its upside down

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of things to work out.

1. First, you need to create a business object/DTO for your save operation
2. Then, you have to write SQL for the insert, update & select operations (Use 'joins' for joining your related tables)- I would recommend you to user an INNER JOIN [SQL Join W3School](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)
3. You can then bind your gridview on presentation layer & either opt for bulk editing through gridview or use a separate form for insert & update operation

Damien.

Answer (score 0):

You should enter DTO Object. Something like that:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        A a = new A();
        B b = new B();
        ABDto abDto = new ABDto(a, b);

    }


}

public class A
{
    public Int32 Id { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }
}

public class B
{
    public Int32 Id { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }
}

public class ABDto
{
    public Int32 Id { get; set; }

    public String AName { get; set; }

    public String BName { get; set; }

    public ABDto(A a, B b)
    {
        AName = a.Name;
        BName = b.Name;
    }
}
```

Comment: After adding the dto object you can do anything you want - Save it to DB, pressent it in gridView or anything else.

Comment: As I expect you can bind List<ABDto> directly to gridview. Or you can convert your List<ABDto> to DataSet